# HttpListener response flushes to soon for 'large' buffers

Tags: .net, buffer, httplistener

I have a service running using Topshelf, which queries data of a proprietary CRM system. This service provides a REST frontend for this CRM system. All works fine and I receive my responses in JSON format.

I have a specific query which returns a JSON response of nearly 500KB. This works well for computers in the local intranet, but when connecting with VPN the connection is a bit slower and all of a sudden the response is partially received and after refreshing I get the remaining part.

Is there a way to make sure the complete buffer is send to the client?

I use the following code:

```
byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);            
context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
context.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", contentType);
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I see here is that you didn't actually call context.Response.Close, which you do need to do.  Closing the response will close the stream, but closing the stream is not documented (as far as I can find) to close the response as well.  Closing the response will close the request object as well, which isn't being closed here either.

It's possible that this will fix the issue.  I can imagine that there were other differences than just network speed in your VPN test; the VPN test may have been from browsers or through proxy servers that only supported HTTP 1.0, which means they would expect the connection to be closed (or they may have been HTTP 1.1, but sending connection: close in the header) before they would think they received the entire response.  Calling Close on the output stream would probably not close the socket, but calling close on the response itself would, and that might end up fixing your issue.

Hopefully this is helpful to anyone else reading in the future.

Harold